# In R, how to calculate mean per column and row respectively?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, mean

I have a data like below.

```
Env<- c("Env1","Env2")
Genotype1<- c(7,3)
Genotype2<- c(9,5)
dataB<- data.frame(Env, Genotype1,Genotype2)

  Env    Genotype1 Genotype2
1 Env1         7         9
2 Env2         3         5
```

Now I'd like to calculate mean per row and column respetively like below table

```
  Env    Genotype1 Genotype2  mean
1 Env1         7         9     8
2 Env2         3         5     4 
  mean         5         7
```

Could you let me know how to do it?

Always many thanks,

Comment: `colMeans()` and `rowMeans()` might be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `colMeans/rowMeans` and append it to data with `rbind/cbind` in `base R`

```
out <- cbind(rbind(dataB, c(Env = 'mean', 
  as.list(colMeans(dataB[-1])))), mean = c(rowMeans(dataB[-1]), NA))
out[out$Env == "mean", "mean"] <- mean(unlist(out[out$Env == "mean", 2:3]))
```

-output

```
 > out
   Env Genotype1 Genotype2 mean
1 Env1         7         9    8
2 Env2         3         5    4
3 mean         5         7    6
```

---

Another option is

```
 addmargins(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(dataB[-1]), dataB[[1]]), FUN = mean)
     Genotype1 Genotype2 mean
Env1         7         9    8
Env2         3         5    4
mean         5         7    6
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! One more question!! Is that possible to calculate the grain mean in the space of NA? I mean NA will be 6 as the grand mean.

Comment: @Jin.W.Kim try the update.  I think it is more easier with `addmargins` (if you can use rownames as the first column